# Magento2 admin create order. Can we add Js variable to order object using config provider like frontend?

Tags: magento2, javascript, admin-order-create

I am working on customization on creating order in admin and I want to access some product attribute in JS. I am looking for model from where I can set order object data and get by window.order.myvariable. Similar to window.checkoutconfig in frontend.